# present perfect have forgotten/ forgot

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

It's night and I haven't cleaned my clothes.

Should I say:

> Oh, I have forgotten to clean my clothes and I will have to do that tomorrow!

Is it good? Or I should use the past simple ("I forgot to clean")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While 1. is grammatically correct, it's not idiomatic.

That's to say, English speakers don't usually talk like that.
Much more likely is:

It's night(time) (or "dark") already and I haven't (yet) cleaned my clothes.

The second example is fine.
In practice most speakers will reduce **I will have to** to **I'll have to**.
Likely alternatives to **do that** are **do it** and **do so**.

While both the present perfect and simple past tenses are possible, because you are talking about a recent occurrence (your forgetfulness) and its implications, the present perfect is preferable.